# how do I use hubot in order to pin item in slack channel?

Tags: coffeescript, slack-api, slack, hubot

is there any option to pin item in slack integrated with hubot by the hubot ?
meaning write code to pin specific message that the robot hears to the channel ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

found the answer by myself : 
need to use slack api, for the specific question I ask I need to use pin.add api

see documentation here : [slack api - pins.add](https://api.slack.com/methods/pins.add)